# How can I refer to a table to make a level system?

Tags: rules, userpoints

I'm working on a RPG website. Users are awarded userpoints (named XP for the need of the "game") depending on their actions.

I want to make a level system based on these userpoints. I already made a table using Drupal Data, which stores values for each level (level number, minimum XP, maximum XP, and some ratios to apply when a user is earning points).

My question is : How can I refer to this table to check a user level (and all the values attached) depending on the user's amount of XP?

I tried with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but no success.

Comment: if your custom table has a column uid you can reference with global $user?!

Comment: My custom table doesn't have a custom uid. This table is only used to store the level values. I wish I could do something like this : when a user gain or lose XP, then check new XP value, then compare to minXP and maxXP values in the table (minXP <= XP <= maxXP), then fill user profile special fields with values taken from the relevant row in the table. The problem is that I'm not a developper at all, so I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Give it some thought to replace that table you made with:

1. a new content type (eg called "XP") and
2. with custom fields as in your question, such as:

   - level number.
   - minimum XP.
   - maximum XP.
   - some ratios.

That way you could create 1 node for each row in your table, with field values matching the values in those table rows. If appropriate, use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to automatically create 1 node for each row in your table.

After you'd have created such nodes, you could use them in combination with the modules you're already using / considering, such as [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

To implement that "*level system*" (as in your question), you can probably use the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm the maintainer of it). If you're not familar with this module, have a look at "[How to implement gamification in a Drupal site and award incentives?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/168)".

Bonus tip: since you're thinking of using [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) already, you may also want to look at the answer to "[How to access current amount of earned userpoints in a Rules Condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146229/how-to-access-current-amount-of-earned-userpoints-in-a-rules-condition/205969#205969)" (pretty sure you'll need something like that also).

PS: All this only requires site builder skills (no need for any custom coding).